# Is it possible to have 2 variables point to the same address in memory

Tags: visual-foxpro

Is it possible in Visual Foxpro to have 2 variables that point to the same address in memory. Such that if the value of one of the variables is changed then the other is also changed. I understand that when passing arguments to functions they can be passed by value or reference but I want to know if this is possible in straight code. I think in other languages such as C this is called a pointer but I don't believe VFP has pointers. So if one writes the following code it will output the number 4.

```
 a=4
 b=a
 a=6
 ? b    && answer 4
```

But could one write code such as the following where the answer could be 6?

```
 a=4
 b=*a   && note the inclusion of the asterisk (pointer?) here which won't compile in VFP
 a=6
 ? b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There are no pointers or references in Foxpro; as you note, the closest thing to it is passing parameters by reference to functions.  You *might* be able to try to kludge something together (as Jerry mentions) with objects using Access/Assign methods, but even then, all that gets passed to the Assign method is the value being assigned - nothing about whether it was originally another variable, a literal value, an object's property, etc.

You could simulate it by using an array or a table.  The variables would contain only the array index or record number (or other index) as a reference, and you'd have to get the actual value from the array or table.

Comment: That's great thanks. I don't particularly want to do it (right now) but I just wanted to make sure it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Visual Foxpro Access and Assign Methods. These methods can be used to execute code when querying a property or trying to change the value of a property. Below is a link  that shows an example:

[Access and Assign Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6y949wx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
a=4
b='a'
a=6
?&b
```